# jQuery selector does not find the view content after document.ready event

Tags: views, javascript

I am applying some jQuery to make a slick carousel from a Drupal view.
The carrousel does not work erratically on page load; sometimes, it does, sometime it doesn't.

```js
jQuery(($) => {
  $(document).ready(() => {
    console.log('ready');
    if ($('.view-carrousel .view-content').length) {
      console.log('content?'); //enters here erratically
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any explanation?

Is it cache bubbling? I added `{{ content|without('field_article_visuel', 'links') }}` to the template.

Is it loading order? I added the following lines.

```yaml
js/amu_slider.js: {}
dependencies:
  - core/views.module
```

Comment: You have to create a Javascript "behavior" for exactly the problems you descibed here. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: I agree - this code isn't using Drupal's JavaScript API.

Comment: Are you using `core/views.module` as dependency in a .libraries.yml file?

Comment: @apaderno yes; bad idea ? i mean, i have corrected it to views/views.module, intending to delay the JS after everything's being loaded from the view

Comment: It just does not do what you probably think. Drupal core expects it to be a library name, not a module name. for example, *core/drupal* is the *drupal* library defined in the [core.libraries.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.libraries.yml/9) file.

Comment: right but views/views.module is a library , no?

Comment: *views/views.module* is a library. Since you used *core/views.module*, it seemed you added a module as dependency.

Comment: The bug would be coming from the module big pipe, and particularely when connected. Anyone experienced such problem?

Answer (score -1):

meanwhile this seems to fix it

```
js/amu_slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - views/views.module
```

Comment: *views/views.module* is the correct library name, since it is the *views.module* library defined in the [views.libraries.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.libraries.yml/9) file.